# Azure Linux App Service as a reverse proxy

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-apps

Is it possible to configure an Azure Linux App Service as a reverse proxy? In Azure App Services running IIS you can use ARR and proxy rewrite rules, what about App Servies running Apache?

apachectl -M shows mod_proxy and proxy_http modules enabled.

Inside .htaccess, I tried using ProxyPassReverse to rewrite the Location field of proxied requests that cause a redirect.

Something like this, returns an error 500:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?img/(.*)$ http://internal.example.com/img/$1 [L,P]
RewriteRule ^/?app/(.*)$ http://internal.example.com/app/$1 [L,P]

ProxyPassReverse / http://internal.example.com/
```

Probably because mod_proxy is not loaded? Would it be possible to load this module?

A Linux App Service is a requirement this time.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing...